# I want to make a sequential model that can be used for probability prediction

Tags: keras, concatenation, sequential

I have built a model that can take both dynamic (timeseries) and static features separately for a classification tasks. The model runs perfectly and gives outputs as expected. The problem is when I want to evaluate the model and plot ROC and AUC curves using predict_proba in scikitlearn.

I found the solution is to make my model sequential. How the following model can be made sequential to get rid of this attribute error.

My model architecture:

```
mdl_input1 = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
x = LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(mdl_input1)
x = LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(x)
x = LSTM(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
mdl_input2 = Input(shape=(X_stat_train.shape[1],))
concat = Concatenate([x, mdl_input2])
output = Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[mdl_input1, mdl_input2], outputs=output)
```

The line I get the error:

```
y_probas = model.predict_proba([X_test, X_stat_test])
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

Schematic of my model:

[image]

Comment: You are already predicting probas with the Softmax as output, just call the model itself, don't add the `predict_proba`

Comment: @CeliusStingher I used the same method but with dynamic feature only and didn't get the error.

`model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.0, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`